# What WDK build environment to choose?

Tags: build, driver, wdk

I am using the latest WDK 7600.16385.1 for building my driver.

My driver is going to work on Windows XP/2003/Vista/7 (x86/x64) operating systems. I do understand that I have to include two versions (x86/x64) of driver within the installation package. But what Build Environment should I choose?

I've built the driver under Windows XP and Windows 7 build environments, but I do not see any differences! Both drivers are working perfect on all operating systems.

So, what does build environment mean? Which one should I choose?

Thanks in advance,

Anthony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, I've just found a wonderful discussion related to my question.

I will post the link here if someone will have the same question as I've asked.

http://www.winvistatips.com/building-common-driver-binary-both-xp-vista-and-7-a-t802832.html

Thanks,

Anthony.

Comment: dead link, needs updating.